# стоит менять HDD на SSD для разработки в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, hdd, ssd

Стоит заменить HDD на SSD для разработки под андроид ? или лучше добавить оперативную память?

Comment: Конечно стоит, если тебя нужна скорость

Comment: Если стоит вопрос выбора между RAM и SSD, то надо выбирать RAM. Если RAM >=16 gb, то дальше наращивать большого смысла уже нет и надо смотреть в сторону SSD

Answer (score 1):

Программы будут работать быстрее, но SSD ненадежные, если брать, то дорогие. Программы типа "сколько осталось жить SSD" бестолковые, т.к. в основном дохнет контроллер. При этом если вы разработчик проекта с закрытым исходным кодом, свои наработки все равно нужно будет хранить или бэкапить на бессмертных HDD (не забывайте про Git).

Comment: Бэкапить лучше на серверах. GitHub, BitBucket, GitLab etc. Ну или на своих серверах. Держать HDD с целью что-то бэкапить, особенно код - не уверен что это оправдано.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб оправдано для ПО с закрытым исходным кодом. Например, компания делает какое-то ПО по заказу Банка, не хранить же исходники на GitHub!) Вы верно подметили про Git, я подправлю ответ, спасибо.

Comment: Git как таковой не имеет никакого отношения ни к хранению, ни к бэкапам. Он точно так же сдохнет вместе с диском без настроенного remote и регулярных пушей в него.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще зависит от ваших текущих параметров, если у вас сейчас к примеру 1GB RAM то это очень мало и необходимо добавлять RAM, но вообще, SSD заметно ускоряет работу.

**Android Studio наиболее требовательна к процессору, затем оперативке и потом уже к SSD.**

**Процессор** - ну тут все просто, чем быстрей тем лучше, я отдал приоритет AMD, больше потоков и тд, для AS самое то.

**RAM** - тут скорей зависит от объема проектов, ну как минимум желательна работа в 2-х или 4-х канальном режиме. Для маленьких проектов по идее будет хватать 4GB и это если без эмулятора, с ним уже будет не очень комфортно, сам же AS вообще рекомендует 8GB, но в идеале как по мне 12GB+.

**SSD** - тут уже не все так просто, но для комфортной работы SSD просто 100% необходим, с ним и сама система будет быстрей работать, и тут следует замечательное НО, если у вас процессор сам по себе очень слабый, то смысла от SSD будет не так много как хотелось бы (для AS), ибо может спокойно случится ситуация когда у вас проц пахает на 100%, а SSD расслабляется, и по итогу скорость работы - не изменится.

Comment: 3.20 GHz   8gb ram

Comment: ну при 8 GB RAM я бы скорей всего SSD поставил, а потом уже по возможности добавил еще 8 GB RAM

Comment: спасибо , я заказал ссд

Answer (score 0):

ССД Ускоряет работу ОС в общем. Загрузка ОС. Ответ программы на 7% быстрее. Работа с процессором на 3-4% быстрее. Работа с памятью быстрее. При изменении кода эмуляция не тормозит, как это бывает с ХДД. Нет 1-2сек задержек. Цена китайского 128гб ссд 25долларов. Нет причин сидеть на ХДД.

Answer (score 0):

**Да! SSD устраняет подавляющее большинство лагов, рекомендую!**

На HDD у меня ВСЁ лагало. Даже менюшки верхней панели открывались за 1.5-3 сек.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).